# Converting code for ATTINY85 to ATMEGA2560. Pin change interupts

Tags: interrupt, atmega2560, port-mapping

I have code that compiles correctly for an ATTINY85 board using the ARDUINO IDE but I don't have an ATTINY85 board. I have an Arduino Mega ATMEGA2560 and when I select this board in the Arduino IDE the code does not compile and throws this error message

```
sketch_feb21a:216:3: error: 'GIMSK' was not declared in this scope

   GIMSK |= _BV(PCIE);                     // Enable Pin Change Interrupts

   ^

sketch_feb21a:216:16: error: 'PCIE' was not declared in this scope

   GIMSK |= _BV(PCIE);                     // Enable Pin Change Interrupts

                ^

sketch_feb21a:217:3: error: 'PCMSK' was not declared in this scope

   PCMSK |= _BV(PCINT2);                   // Use PB3 as interrupt pin

   ^

exit status 1
'GIMSK' was not declared in this scope
```

Here is the code snippet that throws the error

```
void sleep()
{
  GIMSK |= _BV(PCIE);                     // Enable Pin Change Interrupts
  PCMSK |= _BV(PCINT2);                   // Use PB3 as interrupt pin
  ADCSRA &= ~_BV(ADEN);                   // ADC off
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);    // replaces above statement

  MCUCR &= ~_BV(ISC01);
  MCUCR &= ~_BV(ISC00);       // Interrupt on rising edge
  sleep_enable();                         // Sets the Sleep Enable bit in the MCUCR Register (SE BIT)
  sei();                                  // Enable interrupts
  sleep_cpu();                            // sleep

  cli();                                  // Disable interrupts
  PCMSK &= ~_BV(PCINT2);                  // Turn off PB3 as interrupt pin
  sleep_disable();                        // Clear SE bit
  ADCSRA |= _BV(ADEN);                    // ADC on

  sei();                                  // Enable interrupts
}



ISR(PCINT0_vect) {
   /*noInterrupts();
   while (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN) == LOW);

   delay(50);
   while (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN) == LOW);
   playTrack(1 + (curTrack++ % 2));
   delay(400);

   interrupts();*/

}
```

Comment: Do you have a arduino atmega 2560 board? why do you want to put that into sleep mode?

Answer (score 2):

Each processor has different registers, things that control stuff like interrupts, input and output. I would not expect code written for one processor, especially if it directly accesses the registers, to work on another processor.

You would need to look at the datasheet for the Atmega2560 and see how to control its pin change interrupts.

Comment: I have been looking at datasheets for both but I am just having trouble understanding what to change in order to make it work correctly.